# Swagger-UI: 504 ERROR The request could not be satisfied

Tags: api, swagger, azure-web-app-service, swagger-ui

I try to use swagger-ui for my own API that base on Az App-Service.
But there is an error when it executed.

*# The curl command below is work on local.*

**Curl:**

```
curl -X POST "http://<url>/process?parse_id=00001&cust_id=1503&ou_id=317" \
-H  "accept: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-F  "data=@1503.pdf;type=application/pdf"
```

**Response body:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>504 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: xjQNhgn4qv3q67EQL2HVSP_4gAZLPEv_zHqWlDMFRHlh8FhsGmJoGA==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

**Response header:**

```
 content-length: 1033 
 content-type: text/html 
 date: Tue06 Oct 2020 01:57:25 GMT 
 server: CloudFront 
 status: 504 
 via: 1.1 c151a98c4f38ed859d2924662cc3b841.cloudfront.net (CloudFront) 
 x-amz-cf-id: XK3OXYTXGK03GGKf_t4shG4X6x8-50_hzSBnWWw_id2-xOldOk4G-A== 
 x-amz-cf-pop: TPE50-C1 
 x-cache: Error from cloudfront
```

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it is resolved, it is recommended to send out the answer to better help other forum users.

Comment: @JasonPan Not yet :(

Comment: What language your code is, or which document you refer to for operation, I will assist you in solving the problem.